# Testing an infinite sum for convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to find whether or not

$$\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty n^p\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right),\ p > 0$$

converges. I tried the ratio test and got $L = 1$. The root test also revealed $L = 1$. The Cauchy condensation test left me with another complicated sum that didn't obviously converge or diverge, and the terms don't fit the criteria for Dirichlet's test. I can't think of any other series to compare it to and we're not supposed to use the integral test for this one. Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit: I don't have enough reputation to add comments. Yes $\sum \frac{1}{n^\alpha}$ converges when $\alpha > 1$, the proof I have seen of this is by the Cauchy Condensation test.

Comment: Do you know when a series $\sum \frac{1}{n^a}$ converges/diverges?

Comment: The standard thing to do is to multiply top and bottom by $1/\sqrt{n-1}+1/\sqrt{n}$, or something equivalent to that.

Comment: William, please edit from the account that was used to ask the question.

Answer (score 4):

For $p=\frac32$,

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}{n^p\over n^{p-3/2}}\left({1\over\sqrt{n-1}}-{1\over\sqrt n}\right) & =\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{3/2}\cdot{\sqrt n-\sqrt{n-1}\over\sqrt{n(n-1)}}\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}{n^{3/2}\over n\sqrt{n-1}+(n-1)\sqrt n}\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}{1\over\sqrt{1-1/n}+1-1/n}\\
& = \frac12,
\end{align}$$

So, by the limit comparison test, the series converges$\iff$ the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty n^{p-3/2}$ converges. So, the series converges if $p<1/2$ and diverges if $p\ge 1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Do not always go to such theorems that do not work everytime and the conditions can be tricky.

Your sum (positive) is equivalent to $1/2n^{p-3/2}$ (head calculus can be wrong). 
Use the equivalence theorem for positives series, and the Daniel Fischer answer.